# Exactly how does code-signing help software publishers?

Tags: code-signing

I've just finished my first ever code-signing for my app, thanks to the help from [Jeff Wilcox's blog](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/codesigning101/), with his step-by-step instructions, I was able to finish the whole thing in less than 36 hours. But now I start to wonder why I spent the money, because I just can't see how it helps software publishers:

1. There are hackers out there trying to break the protection mechanism in the program by reverse-engineering and modifying the code. But signing the file doesn't prevent this from happening, they still can modify the file's content at will.
2. Sometimes some anti-virus programs may falsely believe my .exe file contains virus. Signing the file doesn't help with that either.
3. Code-signing can only tell the users that this file comes from me, but they still don't know if I'm a good or bad guy. So it's not helping for the users either.

My conclusion is that code-signing is not designed to help software publishers or users. It only tries to keep track of where a file comes from, if it contains a virus, people'd know who planted it, and that's it! (This is true only when hackers are unable to piggy-back a virus into a signed .exe file.)

My question is: Is my understanding correct? Or did I miss something? Thank you.

Comment: Your understanding does gel with this statement from Jeff Wilcox' article "Signing is only a way of proving that some person or company is who they say they are. It doesn’t tell you whether there’s a nice person, or in any way validate functionality of an app."

Answer (score 5):

Signing confirms the authenticity of the code, i.e. that this is *the* code you released, and it has not been tampered with along the way. This has nothing to do with silly code protection, it's a protection for users from imposter software — a single byte modification in the image invalidates the signature. Trust is a whole different matter altogether (AV scanners *might* trust signed executables a bit more than plain unsigned ones, but it's something to discuss with AV vendors).

Comment: Provided that the signature checking mechanism is not somehow circumvented by hackers.  Known attacks exists for the MD5 cipher.  Also they might use alternative streams ( in win ) or resource steams in MacOS to hide their malicious codes.  However it is harder to piggy back something to the signed piece of code than to unsigned one.   Signing the code also doesn't solve the problem when crooks obtain forged certificate from compromised CA that is still trusted by the OS.  There have been recent break-ins into public CA,  and before Verisign has issued M$ code signing cert to unauth person.

Comment: If the Certificate Authority (CA) is doing their job, they will vet the applicant, at least inasmuch as the applicant's identity will be verified.  Bad people prefer to work in the shadows, anonymously.  No security scheme is ironclad, but bad people are also lazy, and if you're house or car has a burglar alarm, they will find one that doesn't.

Comment: @Vlad "crooks obtain forged certificate" - the Stuxnet virus used *TWO* stolen certificates.  and the duqu variant attempts to steal certs! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet

Comment: @Robert  recently it looks like CAs are not doing their jobs.  Without trusted third party code signing is quite useless.  There are some esoteric methods that attempt to solve this problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-carrying_code,  but they are still very far out research project.  Plus they have problems of their own.